# How to update animation or canvas in WPF in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, animation

I have a question about WPF. I write all in Code(C#), without XAML.

*Small program description: I become values from a mobile phone sensors. In wpf program I use this values to make different animation at ellipses on canvas.*

I have a http server in server class, that get values and write it to variables.
In my MainWindow() I invoke it, it brings my Duration for my DoubleAnimation:

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Canvas myPanel = new Canvas();
            ...
            Server server = new Server();
            server.GetData();
            float xxx ;
            xxx = server.duration;
            ...
```

GetData()-make a http request to server, a write response into variable duration. Than I get it through server.duration;

It works perfect.

Here is my Double Animation:

```
 DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation();
        anim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(xxx));
        anim.From = 10;
        anim.To = 0;
        anim.AutoReverse = true;
        anim.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
```

At the end of MainWindow() I add my Object with Animation to Canvas:

```
myObject.BeginAnimation(Ellipse.OpacityProperty, anim);
        myPanel.Children.Add(myObject);
            this.Content = myPanel;
```

It works, but I need to update my duration, when server bring new duration value.

**Question:** How do I make my DoubleAnimation to change when I become new duration values?

**Question in Other Words:** How can I loop server.GetData(); to update my duration values?

**Question in Other Words2:** Is Canvas updating himself automatic?If yes, it invokes automatic server.GetData() in MainWindow()?

I would be very grateful for any examples and descriptions!
Thanks!

Comment: Just every time you get value from server, create a new animation and apply that, this will override the old one. For getting value from server, do at this in `Tick` event of `DispatcherTimer`. Ok, now i want to ask why do you want to do all this ? Are you trying to create some loading like animation ?

Comment: Neeraj,thanks. I have an ellipse on the town map that represents activity in some bar.When people dancing-my ellipse is blinking fast,und so on.  Okey, I should envoke my getdata() in mainwindow() in Tick event of Dispatcher Timer?   Tell me,if I have put my question uncorrectly!Can you give my a small example? Thanks!

Comment: I've put my sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution as i think.

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer(...);
...
// Time interval of large value should be optimal, like 1 minute, 10 minute, etc.
...
timer.Tick += (o, a) => 
{            
        server.GetData();
        float xxx ;
        xxx = server.duration;
        ...

     DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation();
        anim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(xxx));
        anim.From = 10;
        anim.To = 0;
        anim.AutoReverse = true;
        anim.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

    myObject.BeginAnimation(Ellipse.OpacityProperty, anim);
};
```

...